# Pandas: Creating DataFrame from Series

Tags: python, pandas, mat

My current code is shown below - I'm importing a MAT file and trying to create a DataFrame from variables within it:

```
mat = loadmat(file_path)  # load mat-file
Variables = mat.keys()    # identify variable names

df = pd.DataFrame         # Initialise DataFrame

for name in Variables:

    B = mat[name]
    s = pd.Series (B[:,1])
```

So within the loop, I can create a series of each variable (they're arrays with two columns - so the values I need are in column 2)

My question is how do I append the series to the dataframe? I've looked through the documentation and none of the examples seem to fit what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 86):

Here is how to create a DataFrame where **each series is a row**.

For a single Series (resulting in a single-row DataFrame):

```
series = pd.Series([1,2], index=['a','b'])
df = pd.DataFrame([series])
```

For multiple series with identical indices:

```
cols = ['a','b']
list_of_series = [pd.Series([1,2],index=cols), pd.Series([3,4],index=cols)]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_series, columns=cols)
```

For multiple series with possibly different indices:

```
list_of_series = [pd.Series([1,2],index=['a','b']), pd.Series([3,4],index=['a','c'])]
df = pd.concat(list_of_series, axis=1).transpose()
```

To create a DataFrame where **each series is a column**, see the answers by others. Alternatively, one can create a  DataFrame where each series is a row, as above, and then use `df.transpose()`. However, the latter approach is inefficient if the columns have different data types.

Answer (score 45):

No need to initialize an empty DataFrame (you weren't even doing that, you'd need `pd.DataFrame()` with the parens).

Instead, to create a DataFrame where each series is a column,

1. make a list of Series, `series`, and
2. concatenate them horizontally with `df = pd.concat(series, axis=1)`

Something like:

```
series = [pd.Series(mat[name][:, 1]) for name in Variables]
df = pd.concat(series, axis=1)
```

Comment: Tom, that works great - only issue is the columns in the resulting dataframe are named numerically. How would I go about using "name" as the column name in the resulting dataframe?

Comment: Sorry, answered my own question... df.columns = Variables

Answer (score 13):

Nowadays there is a [`pandas.Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) method:

> **`Series.to_frame(name=NoDefault.no_default)`**
>
> Convert Series to DataFrame.
>
> Parameters
>
> `nameobject`, optional: The passed name should substitute for the series name (if it has one).
>
> Returns
>
> `DataFrame`: DataFrame representation of Series.
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> s = pd.Series(["a", "b", "c"], name="vals")
> s.to_frame()
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I guess anther way, possibly faster, to achieve this is 
1) Use dict comprehension to get desired dict (i.e., taking 2nd col of each array)
2) Then use `pd.DataFrame` to create an instance directly from the dict without loop over each col and concat.

Assuming your `mat` looks like this (you can ignore this since your `mat` is loaded from file):

```
In [135]: mat = {'a': np.random.randint(5, size=(4,2)),
   .....: 'b': np.random.randint(5, size=(4,2))}

In [136]: mat
Out[136]: 
{'a': array([[2, 0],
        [3, 4],
        [0, 1],
        [4, 2]]), 'b': array([[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 1]])}
```

Then you can do:

```
In [137]: df = pd.DataFrame ({name:mat[name][:,1] for name in mat})

In [138]: df
Out[138]: 
   a  b
0  0  0
1  4  1
2  1  0
3  2  1

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: That's a nice solution thanks! Is it possible to add an if statement within the dict (or list) comprehension to ignore arrays that are a different size? The dict I end up with from my MAT fiel has a few hundred 2x4000 arrays and a handful of random arrays of different sizes.

Comment: You can add if statement after for ... `{name:mat[name][:,1] for name in mat if ... }`

Comment: Thu use of dict comprehension has the drawback that the keys in standard python dicts are unordered, so the order of columns is not preserved.