# Select specific column from multiple dataframe to combine into one dataframe pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to select specific columns from multiple dataframes and combine them into one dataframe, how can I accomplish this?

df1

```
   count    grade
0   3        0
1   5        100
2   4        50.5
3   10       80.10
```

df2

```
    books   saving
0   4        10
1   5        9000
2   8        70
3   10       500
```

How can I select the `saving` column from `df2` and combine with `grade` column from `df1` to form a separate pandas dataframe that looks like the below.

```
    grade     saving
0   0           10
1   100        9000
2   50.5        70
3   80.10       500
```

I tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame([df1['grade'],df2['saving']])
print(df)
```

but the outcome is not what I wanted.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({  'grade':df1['grade'],   'saving':df2['saving'] })` or `pd.concat([df1['grade'], df2['saving']], axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df = pd.concat([df1['grade'], df2['saving']], axis=1)
```

Similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521511/pandas-creating-dataframe-from-series).

Pandas documentation for this function: [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)